# How can I add and remove custom error note class on select and option html tags?

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

I'm want to show an error message on a `select` dropdown, when user selects nothing and hit submit the error message should appear. 
Here In my code I added two event listners. `submit` and `change`. 
When user hits submit without selecting any option the message appears, but when user selects any country and hits enter the error message still appears. Why is this happening and what's the solution?

```js
const form = document.getElementById("form");
const select = document.getElementById("select-country");
const selectCountry = document.getElementById("select-country").selectedIndex;
const option = document.getElementsByTagName("option")[selectCountry];
const error = document.getElementById("error").style.display = "none";

// console.log(option.value);

form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (option.value === "" || option.value === null) {
    document.getElementById("error").style.display = "block";
    select.classList.add("border-red-500");
    select.classList.add("ring-1");
    select.classList.add("ring-red-500");
    select.classList.add("border");
  }
});

select.addEventListener('change', () => {
  if (option.value === "" || option.value === null) {
    document.getElementById("error").style.display = "block";
    select.classList.add("border-red-500");
    select.classList.add("ring-1");
    select.classList.add("ring-red-500");
    select.classList.add("border");
  }
})
```

```html
<form action="#" class="my-8" id="form">
      <label for="email">Email Address</label>
      <input type="email" placeholder="rendel@renmail.com" class="w-full my-2" id="email" />
      <label for="select-country" class="block my-2">Country</label>
      <select name="select-country" id="select-country" class="w-full my-2">
        <option value="" class="option" selected>Select Country</option>
        <option value="norway" class="option">Norway</option>
        <option value="ireland" class="option">Ireland</option>
      </select>
      <p class="text-xs px-2 border shadow text-red-500 w-full font-semibold" id="error">This field is required!</p>
      <label for="userinput" class="block my-2">Password</label>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Enter password" class="w-full my-2" id="userinput" required />
      <button type="submit" class="py-3 px-12 bg-pink-500 rounded-md text-white font-semibold mt-6">Register</button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `else` statements to hide the error when user selects a value.

To access the selected value, you just need to do `select.value` like below:

```js
const selectCountry = document.getElementById("select-country");

console.log(selectCountry.value);
```

A working example. Let me know if it doesn't fix your problem.

```js
const form = document.getElementById("form");
const select = document.getElementById("select-country");
const selectCountry = document.getElementById("select-country");
const option = document.getElementsByTagName("option")[selectCountry];
const error = document.getElementById("error").style.display = "none";

// console.log(option.value);

form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  if (!selectCountry.value) {
    document.getElementById("error").style.display = "block";
    select.classList.add("border-red-500");
    select.classList.add("ring-1");
    select.classList.add("ring-red-500");
    select.classList.add("border");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("error").style.display = "none"
  }
});

select.addEventListener('change', () => {
  if (!selectCountry.value) {
    document.getElementById("error").style.display = "block";
    select.classList.add("border-red-500");
    select.classList.add("ring-1");
    select.classList.add("ring-red-500");
    select.classList.add("border");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("error").style.display = "none"
  }
})
```

```html
<form action="#" class="my-8" id="form">
      <label for="email">Email Address</label>
      <input type="email" placeholder="rendel@renmail.com" class="w-full my-2" id="email" />
      <label for="select-country" class="block my-2">Country</label>
      <select name="select-country" id="select-country" class="w-full my-2">
        <option value="" class="option" selected>Select Country</option>
        <option value="norway" class="option">Norway</option>
        <option value="ireland" class="option">Ireland</option>
      </select>
      <p class="text-xs px-2 border shadow text-red-500 w-full font-semibold" id="error">This field is required!</p>
      <label for="userinput" class="block my-2">Password</label>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Enter password" class="w-full my-2" id="userinput" required />
      <button type="submit" class="py-3 px-12 bg-pink-500 rounded-md text-white font-semibold mt-6">Register</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: ah, I was so close and thanks for that `select.value` tip